# Whats the best way to backup a MySQL table without file privileges and command line access?

Tags: mysql, backup

Im on a not so great shared hosting plan. I cant get file privileges for mysql so i cant do SELECT INTO outfile, and i dont have command line access so I cant use mysqldump.
What can I do to get a decent table backup?

Answer (score 3):

You say you can't access command line, I think you mean "on the server". But what about the client side ?

From the client, you could still call mysqldump with the '-h' switch to dump locally a table from your server, couldn't you ?

```
mysqldump -ufoo -pbar -hyourserver schema table
```

That should work if your server is not bound to localhost and you have defined accounts correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you install phpMyadmin? If you can, you can try to export through it.